# Postgresql select where array overlaps using like

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to determine if an `ARRAY` column contains overlapping values from another array with the `LIKE` clause?

The `&&` operator works but the strings have to be exact matches

```
 q = """select * from articles where keywords && '{"mortgage brokers"}';""" // Exact match
```

Is it possible to filter the keywords where rows contain values with `substring`, not the full string? Something like:

```
 q = """select * from articles where keywords && LIKE '{"mortgage"}';""" // HOW TO FILTER keywords containing value with substring
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIKE` operates on strings. To check whether two arrays overlap, you can use `&&`.

From [the Array Functions and Operators documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html):

> `&&` : overlap (have elements in common)

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1] arrays_overlap;

| arrays_overlap |
| -------------- |
| true           |
```

---

To see if there are values in an array that are `LIKE` those from another array, one solution would be to unnest both arrays and compare the results with `LIKE`:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
    FROM 
    unnest(ARRAY['abc', 'def' ]) my_array(x)
    INNER JOIN unnest (ARRAY['a', 'z' ]) my_keywords(x)  
        ON my_array.x LIKE '%' || my_keywords.x || '%'
 ) arrays_have_similar_elements;

| arrays_have_similar_elements |
| ---------------------------- |
| true                         |

SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
    FROM 
    unnest(ARRAY['abc', 'def' ]) my_array(x)
    INNER JOIN unnest (ARRAY['y', 'z' ]) my_keywords(x)  
        ON my_array.x LIKE '%' || my_keywords.x || '%'
 ) arrays_have_similar_elements;

| arrays_have_similar_elements |
| ---------------------------- |
| false                        |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qyeQ758QVQeoieFzqTnNsj/1)**

Comment: is it possible to combine `&&` and `like`? `&&` only returns results on exact matches

Comment: @kye: ah I see what you mean now. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @GMB for the guidance. I was able to solve the problem using the query below.

```
      SELECT * from articles, unnest(keywords) my_array(x)
            INNER JOIN unnest(ARRAY['broker']) my_keywords(x)
            ON my_array.x LIKE '%' || my_keywords.x || '%';
```